# is it safe to pass function pointers around and compare them just like normal object's pointers?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Here is the thing, I have several functions,

```
void foo() {}
void bar() {}
```

And I want to pass these functions around just like ordinary objects' pointers,

```
int main()
{
    void (*fptr1)() = foo;
    void (*fptr2)() = fptr1;
    void (*fptr3)() = bar;

    if (fptr1 == foo)
        printf("foo function\n");
    if (fptr2 == foo)
        printf("foo function\n");
    if (fptr3 == foo)
        printf("foo function\n")
}
```

Can I use these function pointers this way? And I wrote a program to test it, seems like ok. Furthermore, I think, not like ordinary objects which may lie in `stack` or `heap`, functions reside in `text segment` (right?), so when I refer to `foo`, does it give me the physical address at which function `foo` lies in the text segment?

**FOLLOW UP**

If I indeed work with DLL, consider this: first, a function ptr `fptr` is assigned a function,

```
ReturnType (*fptr)(ArgType) = beautiful_func;
```

Two scenarios here,

1) if beautiful_func is not in DLL, then it is safe to use this `fptr`.

2) if it is in DLL, then later, I think it would be unsafe to use `fptr`, because it now may refer to a totally different function which is not `fptr` was born for, right?

Comment: Short answer: yes (concepts of process address space vs. physical address space not withstanding). It is *possible* a dynaload library that is unloaded, and a different lib with the same preferred load-addres loaded after, would yield a different function (if you're lucky, more than likely it would just go *boom*). Or unloading and reloading the same .so/dll, but in a different load address. the function would then have a different address as well. But unless you're into doing anything I just mentioned, I would worry very little about it.

Comment: Not all functions are in a text segment.  Also, there can be many text segments.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the part of dynaload lib, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if two function pointers are equal just by simply == them, as they are just normal pointers. That's obvious.

However, when you are say "compare", check what you really have in your mind:

- are you interested in detecting that you are given a different "thing"
- or are you interested in detecting that you are given different function?

comparing pointers (not only function pointers! it applies to all of them) is a bit risky: you are not checking the contents (logical identity), but just the location ("physical" identity). Most of the time it really is the same, but sometimes, beware, you stumble upon copies.

It is obvious that if you create an array with numbers 1,2,3,4 and then allocate another array and copy the contents there, then you get two different pointers, right? But the array may be SAME for you, depending on what you need it for.

With function pointers the problem is just the same, and even more: **you don't actually know** what the compiler/linker has done with your code. It might have opitmized few things, it might have merged some not-exported functions together if it noticed them equal, it might have copied or inlined others.

Especially that may happen when working with bigger separate "subprojects". Imagine you wrote a sorting function, then include it with subproject A, and subproject B, compile/build everything, then link and run. Will you end with one sort functions or two? Hard question until you actually check and tailor the linkage options properly.

This is a bit more complex than with arrays. With arrays, you got different pointer if the array was different. Here, the same function may have many different addresses. It **might** be especially noticeable when working with templates in C++, but that again depends on how well the linker did his job.. Oh, great example: DLLs. With three DLLs based on similar code, they almost have guaranteeded to have three copies of everything they were statically linked to.

And when talkig about DLLs... You know that they can load/unload additional code into your memory, right? This means that when you load a DLL, at some address XYZ a function appears. Then you **unload** it, and it goes away. But when you now load different DLL? Of course the OS is allowed to reuse the space, and it is allowed to map a newly loaded DLL into the same area as previous one. Most of the time you will not notice it, as newly loaded DLL will be mapped into different region, but **it may happen**.

This means that while you can compare the pointers, the only answer you get is: are the pointers same or not?

- if they not same, then you **SIMPLY DON'T KNOW**; different function pointer **does not** mean that the function is different. It may be so, it will be so in 99% of cases, but does not have to be different
- if they are same:

  - if you are NOT loading/unloading the various dynamic libraries large number of times, you might assume that nothing changes and you may be sure got the same function/object/array as before
  - if you are working with unloadable dynamic modules, you'd better not assume that at all, unless you are **absolutely** sure that **none** of the pointers comes from a DLL that will be unloaded in future. Note that it some libraries use dynamic libraries for "plugin-like" functionality. Be careful with pointers from them, and watch for plugin load/unload notifications. Your function may change when a dynamic library is unloaded.

EDIT TO FOLLOWUP:

Unless you (or some library you use) ever **unload** the DLL, then your pointer-to-function-that-targets-a-DLL is safe to use.

Once the DLL is loaded, the only evil thing that can change the meaning of address that this DLL has taken is **unloading the dynamic module**.

If you are sure that:

- (1) either your pointer-to-function does not target a function from dynamic module (points to statically-linked code only)
- (2) or it targets a dynamic module, but that dynamic module is **never unloaded** (ok: until program quits or crashes)
- (3) or it targets a dynamic module, and you precisely know which one, and that dynamic module is sometimes **unloaded** during the runtime, but your code gets some 'prior notification' about that fact

then your pointer to function is safe to store and use and compare, provided that you add some safety measures:

- for (1), no safety measures are needed: the functions will not get replaced
- for (2), no safety measures are needed: the functions will not get until program quits
- for (3), safety measures **are** needed: you must listen to those notifications, and once you get notified about DLL being unloaded, you **must immediatelly forget** all pointers that target DLL. You are still safe to remember any other. You are still safe to re-remember it when it gets loaded again.

If you suspect that your pointer-to-function does targets a function from dynamic module that will be unloaded at some point of time before program quits, and:

- you don't actually know which DLL is pointed by that pointer
- or that DLL will be **unloaded** at any point without any notice

then your pointer to function is **unsafe to use at all**. And by at all I mean AT ALL in any way. Dont store it, as it may instantly evaporate immediately.

Comment: edit: if you have read the unedited version, reread it. I've added important fragment about dynamic libraries

Comment: Absolutely! That's exactly why I point out to rethink what does it mean to "compare functions". With functions, you say "comapre", you are not interested in their LOCATION, but in their BEHAVIOUR. While usually when pointer differs, then so does the behaviour, but it is not guaranteeded. Anyway, the most important part is about dynamic modules which have the power of invalidating any pointer comparisons completely.

Comment: "as they are just normal pointers" Not entirely. Function pointers and other pointers are not inter-convertible.

Comment: @newacct: While semantically not, physically they are. If you cast the function pointer to void* and pass it around, then cast it back to _proper_ type - you can still completely properly invoke the target function. Function pointers ARE pointers. If you want to pick the nits, then you should have mentioned the method pointers from C++ and virtual inheritance, where casting the member pointer to void* erases the information about virtual offset, rendering the pointer completely unusable.

Comment: @alcott: I thought that I've already explained that, but I've added clear answer to my post. Please recheck.

Answer (score 2):

> does it give me the physical address at which function foo lies in the
>   text segment?

Unless you are working on a primitive or any other special OS , **NO!**

The addresses are not **physical , they are [virtual addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)!**

Basically there is a mechanism employed by operating systems that allows programs that are even larger than the physical memory. So the OS does the the job of handling the mapping behind the scenes.

Sorry if i confused you. **Your understanding is correct** (it is perfectly alright to use function pointers in the way you are using them) but the addresses are not physical addresses ( which refers to the numbers using which your main memory is actually addressed ).

Comment: ok, as long as I refer to the same function, then I should get the same virtual address, right?

Comment: 99% yes, see my answer, I'll finish writin it in a minute or two:)

Comment: While this is relevant, it is answering a single word from the question, rather than the whole thing. -1

Comment: @dbaupp: That's why you're supposed to ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Alcott, to add to it, the underlying mapping may always change. i.e. the same physical address where the instructions are stored may change.

Comment: @dbaupp, Ok, but i concurred that the understanding is correct. Which answered the question IMHO. I have highlighted the fact in an edit.

Comment: Yep, I almost forgot that the underlying mapping may change, :-)

Comment: not only mapping may change. when you are working with DLL, even the VA may change, or may be reassigned to another one. Just unload the library and reload a thousand of other libraries. With some luck, previous VA will now point into the body of some other function. But with some bad luck your original VA might also point exactly into the proper prolog - for example, thanks to alignment. I've written that in my post in a bit simpler way

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the C standard allows you to compare function pointers with the operators == and != ,
e.g. from C11 6.5.9:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both
>   are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and
>   a subobject at its beginning) or function,

Exactly where a function resides depends on your platform, it might be in a text segment, or it might be somewhere else. When running on operating systems with [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), the address is normally a virtual address, not a physical memory address.

Comment: remember about dynamic libraries, see my post

Comment: +1 for being the only real answer - that the standard guarantees the equality, and it's not accidental or implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that pointer stores than memory address, which comes down to an number, yes, you can compare tham that way. As for other question, taken from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268), text segment would be defined as "one of the sections of a program in an object file or in memory, which contains executable instructions.", which means, that pointer should containt address of somewhere in the text segment.

Comment: There can be many segments with function data, and functions might not be placed in any segment at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use that way. And you understanding is correct.